# Google Maps with a landmark and description

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

How to create a Google Maps link for embeding in an HTML page with a landmark and description with photo like in the picture bellow?

[image: Map example]

Comment: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/72644?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sebastian, you need to use "infowindow" provide by google maps API. You can see this google example [infowindow example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple?hl=pt-br).

For example:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
var InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map,
    position: myLocation,
    content:
        '<h1>Location pinned from HTML5 Geolocation!</h1>' +
        '<h2>Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '</h2>' +
        '<h2>Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '</h2>'
    });
```

The variable 'map' is your map canvas with your options, than you create a new InfoWindow, with your map, in this example, the postion is my current position ("var myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);"). And the content, you can use html and your variables to create the visual.